# Oracle job alert for DBMS job

Tags: oracle, monitoring, oracle-enterprise-manager, dbms-job

I am trying to create an alert for a dbms scheduler job if it is running for a duration longer than expected. For example, if a job that usually takes 2 hours to run is now running for more than 2.5 hours, I want to be notified.

What would be the best way to do this? Can I use Oracle Enterprise Manager for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this by setting the parameter max_run_duration in the dbms job.
An event will be raised if the job run time exceeds the time mentioned in the property.